# Opening a file in using java

Tags: java, file-io

I'd like to have it so that my java executeble will open a text file up when a Jbutton is pressed.

I dont know where to start so if someone could just nudge me in right direction that would be great

when is searched for opening a file using java it was all about reading in data from a file

Comment: [Basic I/O](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) or [How to Integrate with the Desktop Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html)

Answer (score -1):

Opening a File Pointer:

[File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) f = new [File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)("/path/to/file.txt");

Opening a file input stream (For reading):

[FileInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) in = new [FileInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html)("/path/to/file.txt");

Opening a file output stream (for writing):

[FileOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) out = new [FileOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html)("/path/to/file.txt");

Please take better care to use the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/overview-summary.html) and [Google](http://google.com/).  [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is not here to do your homework for you.

Edit:
To appease @Takendarkk, I've included this:

[Random Access File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) (More advanced that the previous functions, it opens a file with the mannerisms which C/C++ would use.):

RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("/path/to/file.txt", "rw+");

Comment: None of these just open a text file.

Comment: java.io.File is a direct reference to a file header which is - in all technicalities - opening the file.  the fileinputstream opens the file and places the cursor at the start of it, ready for reading.  fileoutputstream opens the file for writing with the cursor at the beginning.   All technicalities considered, every one of the above functions is simply opening the file and awaiting farther directions.

Comment: two seconds - just to make you happy, I will include the RandomAccessFile method... -_-